# Related records parameters

Tags: model, relationship, phalcon

How i can sort and limit a related model collection using parameters ?

It is my Customer model

```
class Customers extends Model 
{
     ...
    public function getOrders($parameters = null)
    {
        return $this->getRelated('Orders', $parameters);
    }
}
```

And i need, get the customer orders sort by creation date and limited, for example:

```
$customer->getOrders([
   'sort' => 'created_at DESC',
   'limit' => '0, 10'
]);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The params allowed are:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/es/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html

Answer (score 2):

here is an example:

```
// model code
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\ServicesVideos', 'service_id', array(
        'alias' => 'videos',
         'params' => [
             'order' => 'ord ASC',
             'conditions' => 'active = :active:',
             'bind' => [
                 'active' => $activeFilter
             ],
             'limit' => 3,
             'offset' => 5
         ]
    )); 
}    

// call it like
$yourObject->videos;
```